# SQL Server Replication riddle

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I am about to implement transnational replication on a project.My Publication server(OLTP)  only keeps data for 3 days, with a procedure I delete all the data from the server.Now as its a replication db this also gets an impact on my main server or the subscriber server.But I don't want to delete data from my main server as like publication server.What is the solution or how it could be done?

Comment: SQL Server or Oracle? Or are you replicating one to the other? If it's a heterogeneous topology, which direction are you going?

Comment: SQL server replication ,using Transnational  Replication,push subscription.One way.

Comment: I want to contract with you for discussing my situation clearly ,can you manage time .It would be great help for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this. First would be to add your delete stored procedure as an article to your publication as with `@type = 'proc exec'` and have the definition of the procedure be a no-op at the subscriber. Now, instead of the deletes coming across, the procedure execution will.

The other is to have `@del_cmd = 'none'` for your table article. This parameter controls what gets called for deletes at the subscriber. By setting it to none, you're saying that you don't want deletes to be applied at all.

Comment: Can you provide me any book or tutorial reference to learn how it's done?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.red-gate.com/library/fundamentals-of-sql-server-2012-replication

Comment: setting @del_cmd = 'none' would mean that any delete that is happening on the publisher outside the stored procedure would not be replicated.

Comment: It means any delete, regardless of how it happened, would not be replicated.